# Problema con PutExtra

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo un problema con los putExtra en Android, al momento de enviar mis datos a otra actividad la misma revienta, coloco código de ejemplo.

Activity 1

```
  ednombre = findViewById(R.id.ednombre);
  edapellido = findViewById(R.id.edapellido);


  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MostrarDatos.class);

  intent.putExtra("nombre", ednombre.getText().toString());
  intent.putExtra("apellido", edapellido.getText().toString());

  startActivity(intent);
```

Activity 2

```
try{
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        txt1.setText(bundle.getString("nombre"));
        txt2.setText(bundle.getString("apellido"));

    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tienes un error bro!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Cualquier ayuda es bien recibida, estoy estancado.

*Edit*
También quisiera saber como seria el putExtra con otros tipos de datos.

Adjunto error que me da.

[image: Aquí el error que me tira.]

Comment: Para añadir, quisiera saber como se haría el putExtra siendo otros tipos de datos.

Comment: "Para añadir ...": Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el añadido ahi. "Revienta": Por favor agregar el error o el stack trace que tira la app.

Comment: Revisando el código me di cuenta que es algo que no había colocado, se me olvido asignarle los id de los TextView a las variables, error de principiante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La app crashea porque txt1 o txt1 es nullo, no por el bundle en si.
mira que hayas declarado el ID correctamente y que esos dos views no sean null.

Te recomiendo poner un 'breakpoint' antes de los setText() en los TextViews y ver si antes de poner el texto, los TextViews no son nulos.

fijate que los hayas declarado antes:

```
private static final String NOMBRE_BUNDLE_KEY = "nombre";
private static final String APELLIDO_BUNDLE_KEY = "apellido";

TextView txt1, txt2;
Bundle bundle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo)
    txt1 = findViewById(R.id.txt_uno_tv)
    txt2 = findViewById(R.id.txt_dos_tv)
    if (getIntent() != null) {
       bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
       if(txt1 != null && bundle.containsKey(NOMBRE_BUNDLE_KEY)) {
          txt1.setText(bundle.getStringExtra(NOMBRE_BUNDLE_KEY))
       } else {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "txt1 es nullo bro!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       if(txt2 != null && bundle.containsKey(APELLIDO_BUNDLE_KEY)) {
          txt2.setText(bundle.getStringExtra(APELLIDO_BUNDLE_KEY))
       } else {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "txt2 es nullo bro!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Es correcto. ya lo he solucionado pero es como dices, no los tenia declarado, error de principiantes, muchas gracias por responder y brindarme otra alternativa.

Comment: De nada, para eso estamos aqui :)

Answer (score 0):

El error es debido a que estas tratando de leer desde los extras del intent y no de los valores del intent prueba con esto

```
try {
    txt1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("nombre"));
    txt2.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("apellido"));
} catch(Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tienes un error bro!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```